# Order ChangeTracker.Entries by modification time

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

There is a code that removes multiple entities:

```
void RemoveCustomerById(Guid id)
{
    var customerPurchases = _context.CustomerPurchases.Where(p => p.CustomerId == id).ToList();
    _context.CustomerPurchases.RemoveRange(customerPurchases);
    
    var customer = _context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    _context.Customers.Remove(customer);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see, it removes CustomerPurchases first and then it removes a Customer. The `SaveChanges` method is overloaded:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
        foreach (var entry in entries)
            FillAdditionalFields(entry);
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This code works fine, but there is one issue. For some reason, `ChangeTracker.Entries()` does not preserve the order in which elements were modified. So, `entries` list always begins with `Customer` and ends with `CustomerPurchases`. It is rather confusing, because `CustomerPurchases` depend on `Customer`. There is no way to actually remove `Customer` from the DB before removing `CustomerPurchases`.

So, is there a way to preserve the order of modifications in `ChangeTracker.Entries()`? Like, overload a method and add a timestamp or something.

Comment: Maybe you need `ChangeTracker.TrackGraph()`? https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-trackgraph-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Nope, it won't do

Comment: Well `TrackGraph` is closest what you can get from EF. Internally EF generates graph of updates/insert/deletes based on dependencies and sorts operations accordingly when generating SQL.

Comment: May not be relevant in your case but you could enable cascade deletes. That way, you would just delete customer and the DB would worry about deleting the orphans: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete